# The nested type `Object Attribute' does not exist in the type `Gtk.Builder'

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm getting this error in every Mono project:

[image]

I have no idea what's the problem as I'm new to Mono.

Anyone help, please.

Comment: I had to remove all references, in VS there was also a list of "current" assemblies in the reference editor which I cleared (press del), now readding the references to the v3.0.0.0 assemblies solved the problem for me.